# GCP: Way to get "paged" via the GCP Cloud Console Android app?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, monitoring, alerting

I'm using GCP and have set up the GCP Cloud Console Android to notify me of errors and alerts.  But my phone is on silent/vibrate most of the time and I miss alerts.  Is there a way to get the GCP Cloud Console Android app to always notify me at full volume?

(My previous experience is with PagerDuty.  Their Android app will ring loudly even if my phone is on silent/vibrate.  I see that GCP has an option to integrate with PagerDuty, but I'm wondering if I can accomplish my goal without and external tool like PagerDuty.)

Comment: Why don't you just send your Google alerts [directly to PagerDuty](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options#pagerduty)?

Comment: Oh, I see my question was unclear.  I updated it to clarify that we're not currently using PagerDuty.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of supported notification channel types available to get notified for Cloud Monitoring alerts. Email, SMS, Webhooks and PagerDuty to name a few. And since you already have a working setup in PagerDuty, same as what Michael Hampton, I would recommend for you to integrate that to Cloud Monitoring.

To configure a PagerDuty notification channel in GCP, you may follow the steps in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options#creating_channels).

Additionally, please keep in mind that Google recommends that you create multiple notification channels for your alert policies as they have no control on most of the delivery system options once the notifications have been passed.

To learn more on alerting policies, you can check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/types-of-conditions).